# For each $g$ there is $[C]\in\mathcal{M}_g$ which embeds on a K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For each genus $g\geq 0$ there is a (smooth irreducible) curve $C$ of genus $g$ which embeds on some K3 surface.

How does this follow from the surjectivity of the period map for K3 surfaces?

Is there a simpler reason for this (apparently) simple fact?
(it seems to me a bit of an overkill to invoke such a strong result - can we actually avoid it?)

Comment: As a close associate of Pooh Bear, I have been asked to pass on the following information: OK, it seems there are more elementary constructions of K3 surfaces with ample line bundles of self-intersection $2d$. See Theorem 2.4.1 (and the references there) in Huybrechts' notes http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf (I tried to add this as an edit, but it was rejected...)

Comment: Excuse me, Theorem 4.2 on page 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if $C$ is a curve on a $K3$ surface $X$, then by adjunction we have

$$g(C) = \frac12 C^2 +1.$$

Now to your question: the cases $g=0$ and $g=1$ (rational and elliptic curves) are easy enough to deal with by hand. So we need to worry about $g \geq 2$. The precise statement about periods (i.e. lattices) we need is

> **Proposition:** For each $d \geq 1$, there exists a K3 surface $X$ (actually a 19-dimensional family of them, but who's counting) with an ample line bundle $H$ such that such that
>   $$\operatorname{Pic}(X) = \mathbf Z \cdot H \ \text{ with } H^2= 2d.$$

(This follows from surjectivity of the period map.)

Now it is apparently a well-known fact (full disclosure: I didn't know it until today!) that every ample linear system on a K3 surface is basepoint-free. Hence by Bertini, the linear system $|H|$ corresponding to the line bundle $H$ above  contains a smooth curve $C$. Putting $C^2=2d$ in the formula above, we get the statement you want.

**Update:** As my close associate Nefertiti mentioned in a comment above, there are more elementary constructions of K3 surfaces with ample line bundles of self-intersection $2d$. See Theorem 2.4.2 (and the references there) on p.35 of [Huybrechts' notes](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf).

Comment: Dear Pooh Bear, thank you for your crystal clear answer. Do you think it's impossible to avoid the surjectivity of the period map to get the statement?

Comment: Dear Heitor, I won't claim it is impossible. One could try to get around it by thinking about what the intersection form on a K3 looks like, and whether one could represent all the even natural numbers by, say, finitely many such forms corresponding to some explicit K3s. To be honest, I don't know if this would work or not. Did you read this argument in a paper? Sometimes authors will invoke a well-known theorem to prove a statement they want, even if it is massive overkill, if it keeps the exposition neat.

Comment: I see. I am afraid I don't have anything more to say, but I assume the speaker had good reason for this assertion...

Comment: Dear Heitor: this is already done --- see the update to my answer.